# In Unity I get this exception error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In Unity, when my player shoots his projectile when I press the fire button the following error pops up as:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <890d6fe26e8c408ea64b353e791fafce>:0)
> ProjectilePooling.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) (at Assets/Jesse's Scripts/ProjectilePooling.cs:29)"

I tried to see if I could find a solid solution to this common error that occurs when index are out of range but I can't seem to solve the logic that I would need to fix it. Would anyone kindly give me some key pointers on how I can fix the error? I would be most thankful for anyone taking time out of their schedule to help help with this issue!

These are the scripts that I am using in my Unity project:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProjectilePooling : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float poolLength;
         
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;

    private List<Projectile> projectilesInPool;

    public static ProjectilePooling Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = GetComponent<ProjectilePooling>();
    }

    void Start()
    {        
        PoolInitialization();       
    }

    //Projectile Instantiation 
    public Projectile Instantiate(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        Projectile _projectile = projectilesInPool[0];
      
        _projectile.transform.position = pos;
        _projectile.transform.rotation = rot;
        projectilesInPool.Remove(_projectile);
        
        return _projectile;
    }

    //Returns the projectile to the pool 
    public void ReturnToPooling(Projectile _projectile)
    {
        _projectile.transform.position = transform.position;
        projectilesInPool.Add(_projectile);
    }
    
    //object pool initialization 
    void PoolInitialization()
    {
        projectilesInPool= new List<Projectile>();      

        for (int i = 0; i < poolLength; i++)
        {
            GameObject _projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            projectilesInPool.Add(_projectile.GetComponent<Projectile>());
        }

    }

   
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttackPower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Transform firingPoint;
    
       
    [SerializeField]
    float firingSpeed;

    public static PlayerAttackPower Instance;

    private float lastShootingInstance = 0;
    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = GetComponent<PlayerAttackPower>();
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (lastShootingInstance + firingSpeed <= Time.time)
        {
            Projectile _projectile = ProjectilePooling.Instance.Instantiate(firingPoint.position, firingPoint.rotation);
            _projectile.Movement();
            lastShootingInstance = Time.time;
        }

    }
  
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 firingPoint;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject shootingObj;

    [SerializeField]
    private float projectileSpeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxProjectileDistance;

    private bool moves = false;
    void Start()
    {
        firingPoint = transform.position;
    }

   
    void Update()
    {
        if (moves)
        {
            MovingTheProjectile();
        }       
    }


    public void Movement()
    {       
        moves = true;
    }

    //Projectile's movement 
    void MovingTheProjectile()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(firingPoint, transform.position) > maxProjectileDistance)
        {
            ProjectilePooling.Instance.ReturnToPooling(this);
            moves = false;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * projectileSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }        
    }
}
```

I tried to see if I could find a solid solution to this common error that occurs when index are out of range but I can't seem to solve the logic that I would need to fix it. I tried seraching for a a few solutions on Google, the Unity forums and also on here related to this subject but I could not get rid of the exception error as every solution seems to be addressing them in different contexts.

Comment: The way to solve it is to step through the code using the debugger to figure out what your logic error is - the exception tells you exactly which line caused the issue, so it's easy to figure out where to start debugging. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: The error happens at ProjectilePooling.cs:29 as per the error. It's probably here: `Projectile _projectile = projectilesInPool[0];`. Set a breakpoint on it to see what exactly happens when it is run.